# Android ListAdapter, Passing selected list items to new activity, creating ParseRelation

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my app, I have the goal of, when a user selects a list item, that ParseObject becomes associated with that user.  I am using a ListAdapter to create a CustomList.

Here is my List Activity:

```
package android.bignerdranch.com.mobilemidwife;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;


public class MidwifeResultList extends ListActivity {


    private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;

    private CustomMidwifeAdapter midwifeListAdapter;

    //calls Adapter; Adapter manages data model
    //adapts it to individual entries in widget
    //inflates, assigns it to rows
    ArrayAdapter<String> madapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


        //initialize main ParseQueryAdapter
        mainAdapter = new CustomMidwifeAdapter(this);

        //which keys in Midwife object
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("practicename");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("education");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("yearsinpractice");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("practicephilosophy");




        setListAdapter(mainAdapter);
        mainAdapter.loadObjects();




    }


    protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)  {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectedMidwife.class);
        intent.putExtra("practicename", "practicename");
        startActivity(intent);


    }

}
```

I have this Adapter:

```
public class CustomMidwifeAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

    public CustomMidwifeAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
            public ParseQuery create() {
                // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to display
                // midwives
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("midwifefirm");
                query.whereEqualTo("userType", "midwife");

                return query;
            }
        });
    }

            @Override
            public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (view == null) {
                    view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_midwife_result_list, null);

                }

                //use midwifefirm as item view/list

                super.getItemView(object, view, parent);


                // find in layout the practice name
                TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.practicename);

                //in the midwifefirm data model, call getPracticename
                titleTextView.setText(object.getString("practicename"));

                // Add education view
                TextView EducationView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.education);

                EducationView.setText(object.getString("education"));

                // Add yearsexperience view
                TextView ExperienceView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yearsinpractice);
                ExperienceView.setText(object.getString("yearsinpractice"));

                //Add practice philosophy view
                TextView PracticePhilosophyView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.practicephilosophy);
                PracticePhilosophyView.setText(object.getString("practicephilosophy"));


                return view;
            }
}
```

Ordinarily, I would setup a for loop, loop through the listitems..not sure where to start.

Thanks for any help.

Michael

Comment: Hey Michael, did my answer help? I've been stuck like you before with parse, so let me know if there is any more help you need.

Comment: Hi, it was helpful..what I am unsure about is, say I have Activity1 that is displaying list items via a listadapter...I want to have the user select on item on the list, then display a more detailed view based on that selection; I know it has to do with passing a bundle...but not sure how to do it in the context of a ListAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have handled custom adapters with listviews using parse. Hopefully this helps.

//setting up the listview

```
mYourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourListView);
mYourCustomAdapter = new YourCustomAdapter(yourActivity.this, new ArrayList<whateverYourParseClassIs>());
mYourListView.setAdapter(mYourCustomAdapter);
```

YourCustomAdapter.java

```
public class YourCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<whateverYourClassIs> {
private final Context mContext;
private List<whateverYourClassIs> mNumbers;
private TextView mNumber1;
private TextView mNumber2;

public YourCustomAdapter(Context context, List<whateverYourClassIs> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.your_layout_for_adapter, objects);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mNumbers = objects;
}


public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_for_adapter, null);
    }

    final whateverYourClassIs individualRecord = mNumbers.get(position);

    mNumber1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number1);
    mNumber2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number2);


    mNumber1.setText(String.valueOf(individualRecord.get("whatever you want")));
    mNumber2.setText(String.valueOf(individualRecord.get("whatever you want")));


    return convertView;
}
}
```

YourQuery

```
public void updateYourData() {
    ParseQuery<whateverYourClassIs> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(YourParseClass.class);
    query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<whateverYourParseclass>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<whateverYourParseclass> objects, ParseException error) {
            if (objects != null) {
                    mYourCustomAdapter.add(objects.get(0));
                    mYourCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

    });
}
```

Or a query that has a loop

```
public void updateYourData() {
    ParseQuery<whateverYourClassIs> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(YourParseClass.class);
    query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<whateverYourParseclass>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<whateverYourParseclass> objects, ParseException error) {
            if (objects != null) {
                mYourCustomAdapter.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                    mYourCustomAdapter.add(objects.get(i));
                    mYourCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
```

In your adapter you simply get the objects (and it's position) passed into it by your query and query specific column names you want to get information from. Let me know if this helps or if you need any clarification.